# Strange behaviour of position absolute inside table-cell on IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, css-position

I have to fix this layout, which is a messy combination of flexbox, table layout and absolute positioning.

While it's working normal on Chrome, FF and Safari, the output screen on IE11 is strange.

In my code, I want the `span` to be at the bottom-right of each square, but on IE11, it appears on top-right instead.

Can anyone please help me to fix this problem? The constraint here is that the flexbox `.container` and the table system must be maintained. I want to fix only the `span` element. Thanks in advance!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.table:before {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
.cell span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="cell">
                Yeah?
                <span>Yo!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="cell">
                Yeah?
                <span>Yo!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your .cell span block and
use below code instead of that.
i have checked its working in every browser.

```
.cell span {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to *fix* it in IE11 is to wrap your `cell` contents into a *block container* and then add `position: relative` to it. Now you can adjust the *position* with `right: 0px` - see demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.table:before {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
.cell span {
  position: absolute;
  /*bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;*/
  right: 0px; /* ADDED */
}

.cell div { /* ADDED */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="cell">
                <div>Yeah?
                <span>Yo!</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="cell">
                <div>Yeah?
                <span>Yo!</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems that the previous coder wants the `span` to be absolute positioned following the whole `.cell` parent. Therefore, what you are doing removes the ability of centering the `span` following `.cell` (one of the most common problem here). Moreover, in fact, inside of `.cell` element is more complicated than this one. I have just replicate the simplest version of the situation, so it's quite risky to change to `position` attribute like that.